# Vue 2 app rendering only one view as blank in production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue 2 app that works perfectly in development. However, in production one of the pages renders as blank. No error messages, no 404. I can't find what is different for this page vs the others that work fine. My router page looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Login",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/Login.vue"),
  },

  {
    path: "/main",
    name: "Main",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/Main.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "Register",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/Register.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/Login.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/players",
    name: "Players",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/Players.vue"),
  },

  {
    path: "/invitations",
    name: "Invitations",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/Invitations.vue"),
  },

  {
    path: "/editplayer",
    name: "Editplayer",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/Editplayer.vue"),
  },

  {
    path: "/message",
    name: "Message",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/Message.vue"),
  },

];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

The .vue file looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-card color="basil">
    <v-card-title class="text-center justify-center py-6">
      <h2 class="font-weight-bold blue--text">
        Sign Up
      </h2>
    </v-card-title>

        <v-card
        color="basil"
          flat
        >

<!--- Start registration form --->
          <v-card-text >

<v-form v-model="valid" >
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-text-field
            v-model="invitationCode"
            label="Invitation Code"
            tabindex="1"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-text-field
            v-model="firstname"
            :rules="firstRules"
            :counter="15"
            label="First name"
            required
            tabindex="2"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>

        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-text-field
            v-model="lastname"
            :rules="lastRules"
            :counter="15"
            label="Last name"
            required
            tabindex="3"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-text-field
            v-model="displayname"
            :rules="displayRules"
            :counter="40"
            label="Name you want others to see"
            required
            tabindex="4"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-text-field
            v-model="email"
            :rules="emailRules"
            label="E-mail"
            required
            tabindex="5"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          cols="6"
          md="6"
        >
        Phone <br />

          <v-text-field
            v-model="phone"
            hint="Numbers Only!"
            required
            tabindex="6"
          ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>


        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-text-field
           v-model="password"
            :append-icon="show1 ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
            :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
            :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
            name="passowrd"
            label="Password"
            hint="At least 8 characters"
            class="input-group--focused"
            @click:append="show1 = !show1"
            tabindex="7"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-text-field
           v-model="password2"
            :append-icon="show1 ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
            :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
            :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
            name="password2"
            label="Re-enter your password"
            hint="At least 8 characters"
            class="input-group--focused"
            @click:append="show1 = !show1"
            tabindex="8"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-btn  tabindex="9"
      class="orange" @click="register()"><v-icon>mdi-check</v-icon></v-btn>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
          </v-card-text>

        </v-card>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import EventService from '../Services/EventServices'
  export default {
    name: "Register",
    data () {
      return {
     valid: false,
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      phone: '',
      firstRules: [
        v => !!v || 'First name is required',
        v => v.length <= 10 || 'Name must be less than 15 characters',
      ], 
      lastRules: [
        v => !!v || 'Last name is required',
        v => v.length <= 10 || 'Name must be less than 15 characters',
      ],      
      displayRules: [
        v => !!v || 'Display name is required',
        v => v.length <= 40 || 'Name must be less than 40 characters',
      ],
      phoneRules: [
        v => !!v || 'Phone number is required',
        v => v.length <= 40 || 'Name must be less than 40 characters',
      ],
      displayname: '',
      userInfo: [],

      password: '',
      password2: '',
      show1: false,
      message: '',
      invitationCode: '',
      email: '',
      emailRules: [
        v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
        v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
      ],
      rules: {
      required: value => !!value || 'Required.',
      min: v => v.length >= 8 || 'Min 8 characters',
      emailMatch: () => (`The email and password you entered don't match`),
    },
      }
    },

  methods: {
    async register() {
//      console.log('inlogin.vue, starting register ')
      var areaCode = this.phone.substr(0, 3)
      var prefixCode = this.phone.substr(3,3)
      var phoneLine = this.phone.substr(6,4)
      await EventService.registration(this.email, this.firstname, this.lastname, this.displayname, this.password, areaCode, prefixCode, phoneLine, this.invitationCode)
      .then(
        (registerReturn => {
          if (registerReturn === 'invalid') {
            this.regError = "Invalid Invitation Code with this Email Address."
          } else {
//            console.log('registered', registerReturn)
            this.$router.push("/")
          }
            
        })

      );
    }
  }
  }
</script>

<style>
/* Helper classes */
.basil {
  background-color: #FFFBE6 !important;
}
.basil--text {
  color: #356859 !important;
}
</style>
```

If it helps, the live page is at https://0-0-2.net/register. I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this since it works in development. I'm guessing there's something breaking during the build process? How would you suggest I work through that?

Comment: I would suggest replacing `Register.vue` with just a very simple template - if that works in live then your issue is with code, otherwise it's more fundamental. If the simple template works then add back in functionality bit by bit until it breaks to see where the issue is.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this isn't relevant to Vue at all. You can  clearly see that /register response is blank. The problem is totally on server side which isn't described.

Answer (score 0):

match, thank you for the reminder about going back to the basics. I replaced the file and it still did not work. But it did at least eliminate a problem with that file.

For anyone seeing this later, what I did to fix the problem was

--Rename the file to Registration.vue

--changed

```
export default {
    name: "Register",
```

to:

```
export default {
    name: "Registration",
```

--Updated the route accordingly. Reran the "npm run build" command.

All worked fine. My best guess is some kind of caching problem somewhere along the line. It may not have gotten to the root problem but it got my app working and kept my efforts moving along.